# Allow only valid characters in a Windows file system in a TextBox that can only appear as uppercase in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can only valid characters be allowed in a Windows file system in a TextBox that can only appear as uppercase in Windows Forms?

Is there an easy way for this?

1. About the set of characters allowed in a Windows file system (`Char.IsLetterOrDigit` is not enough)
2. How do I make the typed characters uppercase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Textbox key press handler and Use [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx), [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) to check for a valid char and return the uppercase version if the char is valid.

```
   textBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper; 

   ...

   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains(e.KeyChar) ||
            Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Contains(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

[Of course, it would be more reusable to create a method rather than placing this code directly in the handler.]

UPDATED to reflect comments.

Comment: e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar); doesn't work though. I used the CharacterCasing property from the previous reply.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a minor change. If you want to allow the user to use backspace and other control characters you should check for Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) within your condition

Comment: True, but how would the user correct an error if the control doesn't accept backspace? This only became apparent to me when I used your solution in a project earlier today and became stuck whilst testing because I couldn't use backspace. I had to use a combination of arrow keys and delete which worked but wasn't particularly user friendly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution. It works perfectly for windows file names convention. Cheers.

```
 // Prevent user from wrong input - \/:*?"<>|
        private void textBoxMP3Name_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), @"[^?:\\/:*?\""<>|]"))                                                                                        
            {                                                                           
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Better way for me was to use the TextChanged Event ala:

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

...

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
    textBox1.Text = string.Join("", textBox1.Text.Split(invalidChars));
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length + 1;
}
```

because ... you need backspace and user simply love copy & paste ...